# How to run a "docker run .." command from within a shell script

Tags: docker, shell

I have a shell script containing a call to docker run. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Local directory where your data is.
PATH_TO_EXPORTS="/home/user/data"
iType_NAME="iType.csv"
colIDs="X,Y,W,Z"
FLAG="FALSE"

#These next three variables don't need to, and should not be changed.
#They refer to locations within the docker container - DO NOT CHANGE !!!
IMG_EXPORTS_DIR="/home/rstudio/project/exports"

#Execute docker run to carry out your analysis
docker run -v $PATH_TO_EXPORTS:$IMG_EXPORTS_DIR \
           -e PATH_TO_EXPORTS=$IMG_EXPORTS_DIR \
           -e iType_NAME=$iType_NAME \
           -e colIDs=$colIDs \
           -e FLAG=$FLAG \
           --user "$(id -u)" \
           my_docker_image:3.0
```

If I try to run this script via command line by calling: `sh myScript.sh` , I get the following error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

However, if I manually run the `docker run ...` command on the command line, everything  works as expected.

Does anybody know why this `docker run ...` command fails when inside a shell script ?

Many thanks in advance !

-M.

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if it’s caused by an unquoted variable.

Comment: You can run your script with `sh -x myScript.sh` to get an idea of what is being run.

Comment: What is your full manual command that you run?

Comment: convert all variables in the docker run command to be `"${var_name}"`. eg...
`$PATH_TO_EXPORTS` -> `"${PATH_TO_EXPORTS}"` and the same for the others. See if this helps